# Alter Session to set Date Format in MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, mybatis

How can I do this in the same transactional session?

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'
```

There are some procedures and insertes that I need to execute this before them.
I've tried to make another method, in the same one, but it still doesn't work.

I have MyBatis integrated with Spring. I don't know if it makes any difference.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

SOLUTION:

I'v managed this to work by changing the way Spring and MyBatis integrates through SqlSession.

Comment: If possible, it would be better to fix the underlying bug by changing the inserts and procedures to not rely on a default format.

Comment: this is not possible, that's why I'm trying to make this work.

Comment: if your using an oracle client on the server side you can change the registry value of NLS_DATE_FORMAT or just issue an `alter system set NLS_DATE_FORMAT=...` in the database.

Comment: I can't do that. It's an application database.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two possible solutions.

## Extend SqlSessionFactory

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.ExecutorType;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.TransactionIsolationLevel;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class CustomSqlSessionFactory extends DefaultSqlSessionFactory
{
    private static Logger   msLogger    = Logger.getLogger(CustomSqlSessionFactory.class);

    public CustomSqlSessionFactory(Configuration configuration)
    {
        super(configuration);
    }

    @Override
    public SqlSession openSession()
    {
        SqlSession session = super.openSession();
        alterSession(session);
        return session;
    }

    protected void alterSession(SqlSession session)
    {
        try
        {
            Statement statement = session.getConnection().createStatement();
            statement.addBatch("alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'");
            statement.addBatch("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = LINGUISTIC");
            statement.addBatch("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = XTURKISH_AI");
            statement.executeBatch();
            msLogger.debug("Altered newly created session parameters.");
            statement.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            msLogger.error("Alter session failed!", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SqlSession openSession(boolean autoCommit)
    {
        SqlSession session = super.openSession(autoCommit);
        alterSession(session);
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public SqlSession openSession(Connection connection)
    {
        SqlSession session = super.openSession(connection);
        alterSession(session);
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public SqlSession openSession(ExecutorType execType)
    {
        SqlSession session = super.openSession(execType);
        alterSession(session);
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public SqlSession openSession(ExecutorType execType, boolean autoCommit)
    {
        SqlSession session = super.openSession(execType, autoCommit);
        alterSession(session);
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public SqlSession openSession(ExecutorType execType, Connection connection)
    {
        SqlSession session = super.openSession(execType, connection);
        alterSession(session);
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public SqlSession openSession(ExecutorType execType, TransactionIsolationLevel level)
    {
        SqlSession session = super.openSession(execType, level);
        alterSession(session);
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public SqlSession openSession(TransactionIsolationLevel level)
    {
        SqlSession session = super.openSession(level);
        alterSession(session);
        return session;
    }
}
```

If you are using spring also create a CustomSqlSessionFactoryBuilder

```
import org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder;

public class CustomSqlSessionFactoryBuilder extends SqlSessionFactoryBuilder
{
    @Override
    public SqlSessionFactory build(Configuration config)
    {
        return new CustomSqlSessionFactory(config);
    }
}
```

and attach CustomSqlSessionFactoryBuilder by modifying the SqlSessionFactoryBean configuration

```
<bean id="mySqlSessionFactoryBuilder" class="your.package.CustomSqlSessionFactoryBuilder" />    

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBuilder" ref="mySqlSessionFactoryBuilder" />
</bean>
```

Session will be altered on each borrow operation. However, if you are using pooled connection, this approach will degrade the execution performance. Hence on every checkout of the connection from the pool, openSession will be called.

If you are using a pooled data source then handling session alter operations on data source level will be much faster. Second solution modifies C3P0 pooled data source for altering session.

## Modify Pooled Data Source (C3P0 and Spring)

Create a connection customizer class [1]

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractConnectionCustomizer;

public class ConnectionCustomizer extends AbstractConnectionCustomizer
{
    private static Logger   msLogger    = Logger.getLogger(ConnectionCustomizer.class);

    public void onAcquire(Connection c, String pdsIdt)
    {
        try
        {
            Statement statement = c.createStatement();
            statement.addBatch("alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'");
            statement.addBatch("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = LINGUISTIC");
            statement.addBatch("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = XTURKISH_AI");
            statement.executeBatch();
            msLogger.debug("Altered newly created session parameters.");
            statement.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            msLogger.error("Alter session failed!", e);
        }
    }   
}
```

Modify data source configuration bean and add created class as **connectionCustomizerClassName**

```
<!-- 
    driverClass : Driver class that will be used to connect to database.
    jdbcUrl : jdbc url defining the database connection string.
    user : username of the database user.
    password : password of the database user.
    acquireIncrement : how many connections will be created at a time when there will be a shortage of connections.
    idleConnectionTestPeriod : after how much delay a connection will be closed if it is no longer in use.
    maxPoolSize : Max number of connections that can be created.
    maxStatements : Max number of SQL statements to be executed on a connection.
    minPoolSize : Minimum number of connections to be created.
    connectionCustomizerClassName : Custom connection customizer to enable session alterations and jobs on acquiring/closing - checking in/out physical connections 
-->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${app.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${app.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${app.jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
    <property name="connectionCustomizerClassName" value="your.package.name.ConnectionCustomizer" />
</bean>


[1]: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/
```